# Garbled console output when installing Symfony2 on Windows

Tags: php, windows, symfony

I'm trying to install Symfony 2 on Windows 7. When I run

```
php symfony.phar
```

or

```
php symfony.phar new proj_name
```

I get very long garbled output (random characters) in console window and little else happens. Any suggestions what this may be?

I have PHP 5.4 installed with UniServerZ WAMP stack and a quite fresh installation of Windows 7.

Comment: Can you show us the screenshot of that garbled text?

Comment: Well, I saved it into a txt file and it's simply the symfony.phar archive content. May it be a problem with executing phar files?

Comment: Have you added `php` path to your windows `PATH` environment variable? Anyway, try Composer instead, as Composer is preferable way to install Symfony.

Comment: PHP works fine if that's what you mean, at least I can run php somefile.php or php -i and it works as expected, I'm trying to create a sample phar file now to check if it'll work.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what's the problem with phar but composer way did work-  thanks for the suggestion.